# Dafny: BST delete proof

Tags: binary-search-tree, verify, dafny

I want to proof the delete function is a binary search tree after deleting an element.
the delete function seems to be correct, but its just not enough to ensures it is a binary search tree. Is there any idea how to do it?
It fails to ensure when the function is recursive.
The size function is also added.

```
datatype Tree = Nil | Node(ltree: Tree, v: int, rtree: Tree)

function isBinarySearchTree(tree: Tree) : bool
  decreases tree
{
  match tree
  case Nil => true
  case Node(ltree,v,rtree) =>
    && isBinarySearchTree(ltree) && isBinarySearchTree(rtree)
    && lesser(rtree, v) && greater(ltree, v)
}

function max(x:int, y:int): int
{
  if x < y then y else x
}

function min(x:int, y:int): int

{
  if x < y then x else y
}

function greater(tree: Tree, max: int) : bool
  decreases tree
  ensures tree == Nil ==> true
{
  match tree
  case Nil => true
  case Node(ltree,v,rtree) => (max > v) && greater(ltree, max) && greater(rtree, max)
}

function lesser(tree:Tree,min: int) : bool
  decreases tree
  ensures tree == Nil ==> true
{
  match tree
  case Nil => true
  case Node(ltree,v,rtree) => (min < v) && lesser(ltree, min) && lesser(rtree, min)
}

function Deletion(tree:Tree, v:int): Tree
  requires isBinarySearchTree(tree)
  decreases Size(tree)
  ensures forall ltree: Tree, x: int, rtree: Tree:: tree == Node(ltree, x, rtree) && (x == v) && (ltree == Nil) ==> isBinarySearchTree(Delete(tree, v))
{
  match tree
  case Nil => Nil
  case Node(ltree, x, rtree) =>
    if (v < x) then Node(Delete(ltree, v), x, rtree)
    else if (x < v) then Node(ltree, x, Delete(rtree, v))
    else match ltree {
           case Nil => rtree
           case Node(ltree2, v2, rtree2) =>
             Node(ltree2, v2, Delete(Node(rtree2, x, rtree), v))
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dafny can automate a lot of proofs but only when they are straightforward to it.
In your case, after reading the code, I have myself a hard time figuring out if it's correct or not, so I won't blame Dafny on this one.

Rather than putting "ensures" on functions, I would strongly suggest you start your proof in a separate lemma. In the code below, I also moved the ensures of the Size into a separate lemma. Otherwise, making it always available for any argument could trigger Dafny into instantiating it for values you wouldn't like, which can vastly increase verification time.

Doing so lets you use the power tools of [verification debugging](https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-verification-debugging)

Here is some code to get you started. Try to prove the failing assertions.

```
datatype Tree = Nil | Node(l: Tree, v: int, r: Tree)

function isBinarySearchTree(t: Tree) : bool
  decreases t
{
  match t
  case Nil => true
  case Node(l,v,r) =>
    && isBinarySearchTree(l) && isBinarySearchTree(r)
    && lesser(r, v) && greater(l, v)
}

function Size(t:Tree): (value : int)
  ensures value >= 0
{
  match t
  case Nil => 0
  case Node(l, v, r) => 1 + Size(l) + Size(r)
}
lemma AboutSize(l: Tree, v: int, r: Tree)
  ensures Size(Node(l, v, r)) > Size(l)
  ensures Size(Node(l, v, r)) > Size(r)
{
  
}

function max(x:int, y:int): int
{
  if x < y then y else x
}

function min(x:int, y:int): int

{
  if x < y then x else y
}

function greater(t: Tree, max: int) : bool
  decreases t
  ensures t == Nil ==> true
{
  match t
  case Nil => true
  case Node(l,v,r) => (max > v) && greater(l, max) && greater(r, max)
}

function lesser(t:Tree,min: int) : bool
  decreases t
  ensures t == Nil ==> true

{
  match t
  case Nil => true
  case Node(l,v,r) => (min < v) && lesser(l, min) && lesser(r, min)
}

function Delete(t:Tree, v:int): Tree
  requires isBinarySearchTree(t)
  decreases Size(t)
  ensures Size(Delete(t, v)) == Size(t) - 1 || Delete(t, v) == t
{
  match t
  case Nil => Nil
  case Node(l, x, r) =>
    if (v < x) then Node(Delete(l, v), x, r)
    else if (x < v) then Node(l, x, Delete(r, v))
    else match l {
           case Nil => r
           case Node(l2, v2, r2) =>
             Node(l2, v2, Delete(Node(r2, x, r), v))
         }
}
lemma LeftIsBinarysearchTree(r: Tree, v: int)
  requires isBinarySearchTree(Node(Nil, v, r))
  ensures isBinarySearchTree(Delete(Node(Nil, v, r), v))
{
}
lemma RightIsBinarysearchTree(l: Tree, v: int)
  requires isBinarySearchTree(Node(l, v, Nil))
  ensures isBinarySearchTree(Delete(Node(l, v, Nil), v))
{
}


lemma {:vcs_split_on_every_assert} {:rlimit 1000} eleteReturnsBinarySearchTree(t: Tree, v: int)
  requires isBinarySearchTree(t)
  ensures isBinarySearchTree(Delete(t, v))
{
  if t.Nil? {
    // Proven automatically
    assert Delete(t, v).Nil?;
    assert isBinarySearchTree(Delete(t, v));
  } else {
    assert t.Node?;
    assert isBinarySearchTree(Delete(t, v));
  }
}
```